# Как связать воедино сайт, регистрацию и капчу?

Tags: веб-программирование

Здравствуйте всем, учусь делать сайты пока на Denwere, Вот подошёл к очередному препятствию - есть сайт, есть регистрация, есть капча, а как это все увязать в целое, чтобы страница сайта открывалась после регистрации и естественно капча работала в регистрации? Подскажите пожалуйста, кто имеет такой опыт.

Comment: когда пользователь ввел данные для регистрации, + ваш код из капчи, данные отправляются на сервер для проверки, на сервере идет сверка кода капчи с тем что ввел пользователь.

Answer (score 1):

Делять сайты на Денвере - это как? Если вам нужна регистрация (да и другие действия, требующие определенной логики и проверки/хранения данных) вам уже без хотябы начальных знаний PHP (или других языков, на которых пишутся серверные сценарии) не обойтись! Так что или изучайте или нанимайте фрилансера, который сделает за вас эту работу.

Comment: Но если я ошибаюсь и вы все-таки знаете ПХП, то для решения вашей задачи глядите в сторону механизма сессий (session_start(), $_SESSION и т.д.)

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте для начала сделать хотя бы:

> 2 = 2 ? "Да","Нет".

И если нажмут "Да", тогда открыть сайт. И вообще лучше найти какой нибудь справочник или книгу, для того, чтобы вообще понимать, что вы делаете. А то такими темпами, у вас ничего не получится.

Comment: Вот хорошая страничка. Где подробно рассказывается как защитить страницу паролем и прочие полезные штуки. http://www.php.su/articles/?cat=security&page=007

Comment: ну и к тому же есть еще такая вещь как [google reCaptcha][1].

[1]: https://www.google.com/recaptcha